# Expectations of a stochastic process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expectation, stochastic-calculus

Studying for a test and came across this question for practice

Given

$dX(t) = X(t)dW(t)$ where $W(t)$ is the Weiner process and X(t) is a process governed by dX(t) and X(0) = 2, I want to find the expected value $E[e^{-t}X^{2}(t)]$.

So far, I've been able to arrive at

$X(t) = X(0) + \int_{0}^{t}(X(u)dW(u))$

and

$X^2(t) = X(0)^2 + 2X(0)\int_{0}^{t}X(u)dW(u) + \int_{0}^{t}X^2(t)du$

So the

$E[e^{-t}X^2(t)] = e^{-t}E[4 + 4\int_{0}^{t}X(u)dW(u) + \int_{0}^{t}X^2(t)du]$

By linearity of expectation, this is simplified to :

$e^{-t}(4 + 4E[\int_{0}^{t}X(u)dW(u)] + E[\int_{0}^{t}X^2(t)du])$

Since $\int_{0}^{t}X(u)dW(u)$ is an ito integral, it is a martingale and it's expectated value will be $0$ so I finally arrived at

$e^{-t}(4 + E[\int_{0}^{t}X^2(t)du])$.

How can I proceed from here?

Comment: Itô's isometry readily yields $$E(X_t^2)=E\left(\int_0^tX_sdW_s\cdot\int_0^tX_sdW_s\right)=E\left(\int_0^tX_s^2ds\right)=\int_0^tE(X_s^2)ds$$ hence the function $u(t)=E(X_t^2)$ solves $u(0)=E(X_0^2)$ and $$u(t)=\int_0^tu(s)ds$$ Thus, $$u(t)=u(0)e^t$$ that is, $$e^{-t}E(X_t^2)=E(X_0^2)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple approach is by noting that
\begin{align*}
X_t = X_0 e^{-\frac{1}{2}t + W_t}.
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
E\left(e^{-t}X_t^2 \right) &= E\left(4e^{-2t+2 W_t} \right)\\
&=4e^{-2t + \frac{4t}{2}} =4.
\end{align*}

Comment: Could you please help me with how you reached the value of X(t) in your first step?

Comment: @Newtt: use Ito's lemma to find $d\ln X_t$.

Comment: Right and how do you go from $E\left(4e^{-2t+2 W_t} \right)\\$ to 
$4e^{-2t + \frac{4t}{2}}$.

Comment: @Newtt: For any $\xi\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, $E(e^{\xi} ) = e^{\mu + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}}$.